# PostgreSQL query to get events occurring within microseconds of each other

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ruby on Rails' ActiveRecord's [`destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) method generates one SQL `DELETE` query per record. We have a page in a web application that allows a user to delete associated records. Since the `deleted_at` timestamps are off by a few microseconds, it becomes challenging to group all the records that were deleted at the same time. Here is some example data:

`id |         deleted_at

----+----------------------------
 71 | 
 45 | 2014-04-29 18:35:00.676153
 46 | 2014-04-29 18:35:00.685657
 47 | 2014-04-30 21:11:00.73096
 48 | 2014-04-30 21:11:00.738533
 49 | 2014-04-30 21:11:00.745232
 50 | 
 51 | 
(8 rows)`

So you can see there were two events here, one affecting 2 rows (with ids 45 and 46) and one affecting 3 rows (with ids 47, 48, and 49). My question is how can I query this table so that each event is grouped into a single row? I've considered using `extract(microseconds from r.deleted_at)` but that would fail if the seconds were wrapped. I want a query, or even a function that compares each record and groups those with `deleted_at` within a certain threshold of each other.

Edit: I should mention that I can't use `delete_all` because I want callbacks to be run. We are using the [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem to soft-delete records.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. Instead of depending on ActiveRecord callbacks, I can simply set the timestamp manually using `update_all`. So instead of `Model.where(...).delete_all` I do `Model.where(...).update_all(deleted_at: Time.current)`. Now I can easily group by timestamp.

If anyone wants to answer the original PostgreSQL query question, I'll be glad to choose the correct answer for points.